# signaling Raspberry Pi with PLC

Tags: raspbian, gpio, rpi.gpio, led

I want to give signal via PLC to Raspberry Pi and when the raspberry pi gets that signal, it should run the python script and when the python script execute properly and cycle is completed, it should wait for the other signal from PLC to again run the same script and same cycle should go on.

here is my snippet:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from picamera import PiCamera
from PIL import Image
camera = PiCamera()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
RedLedPin = 36
GreenLedPin = 38
PLC_Input_signal = 37
GPIO.setup(PLC_Input_signal, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(RedLedPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GreenLedPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.input(PLC_Input_signal)
GPIO.output(RedLedPin, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(GreenLedPin, GPIO.HIGH)
if (GPIO.input(PLC_Input_signal) == GPIO.LOW):
    time.sleep(10)
    camera.resolution = (4056, 3040)
    camera.start_preview()
    
else:
    print('Signal Not Received')
GPIO.input(PLC_Input_signal) == GPIO.HIGH
GPIO.cleanup()
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but when i am providing 5v supply to gpio pin i.e. as defined in code pin 37, it is not working accordingly. please help me out. please note that gpio is active low pin which gpio.low turns on the power while gpio.high turns off the power

please help me out

Comment: The GPIO pins are not 5V tolerant. You can damage the pin or the Pi by doing so.

Comment: @SteveRobillard can you suggest what is the error then

Comment: ?? One error is as Steve explained - the GPIO pins are designed to handle 3.3V... ***NOT*** 5V. If you're looking for someone to debug your code, you might have better luck at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

An experienced developer would approach your issue (which is unclear) on a step by step approach .

1. Detect a signal
2. Write code to do something with signal
3. Next step.

Start with 1

Comment: @Gil why are you addressing this to me? Nothing to do with my answer.